# Creating dask dataframe from array doesn't keep column types

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I'm trying to create a dask dataframe from a numpy array. For that, I need to specify the column types. As suggested in dask documentation, I use for that a pandas empty dataframe. This doesn't throw an error, however all the data types are created as `object`. I need to use the empty Pandas dataframe, how to make this work?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

array = np.array([(1.5, 2, 3, datetime(2000,1,1)), (4, 5, 6, datetime(2001, 2, 2))])
meta = pd.DataFrame({'col1': pd.Series(dtype='float64'),
                   'col2': pd.Series(dtype='float64'),
                   'col3': pd.Series(dtype='float64'),
                   'date1': pd.Series(dtype='datetime64[ns]')})
print(meta.dtypes)

>>> col1            float64
>>> col2            float64
>>> col3            float64
>>> date1    datetime64[ns]
>>> dtype: object

columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'date1']
ddf = dd.from_array(array, columns=columns, meta=meta)
ddf.compute()

print(ddf.dtypes)

>>> col1     object
>>> col2     object
>>> col3     object
>>> date1    object
>>> dtype: object
```

Comment: How is this different from yesterday's question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836962/dask-from-array-converts-types-to-object

Comment: It’s using an empty pandas frame

Comment: It looks like this is a bug-- I would encourage you to submit an [issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/contribute). Including @Alexandra Dudkina's additional [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70838194/17015034) could be helpful for debugging.

Comment: Update to my above comment-- this is not a bug, but more of a nuance around how the `meta` argument works. There is some discussion [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8585) on how to improve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could dtypes be set after dataframe creation?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import dask.dataframe as dd

array = np.array([(1.5, 2, 3, datetime(2000,1,1)), (4, 5, 6, datetime(2001, 2, 2))])

columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'date1']
ddf = dd.from_array(array, columns = columns)
ddf.compute()

ddf = ddf.astype({'col1': 'float64','col2':'float64','col3':'float64','date1':'datetime64[ns]'})
print(ddf.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work -

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])
      .astype({"col1": "float64", 
               "col2": "float64", 
               "col3": "float64", 
               "col4": "datetime64[ns]"}))
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
```

The output of `ddf.dtypes` gives me the correct data types.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to create the data frame with dd.from_array